# How to use/activate move_slow_and_clear?

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use [move_slow_and_clear](http://wiki.ros.org/move_slow_and_clear) recovery behavior but there is very limited documentation on it.
Could someone help me with the setup required to activate or use the recovery behaviour?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/386422/how-to-use/activate-move_slow_and_clear?/) by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) on ROS Answers with karma: 463 on 2021-09-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-09-13**:
Have you looked at the source code to understand behaviour: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/noetic-devel/move_slow_and_clear/src/move_slow_and_clear.cpp?

To use it:

~/clearing_distance (double, default: 0.5)

The radius away from the robot in meters inside of which obstacles will be cleared.
~/limited_trans_speed (double, default: 0.25)

The translational speed in meters/second the robot will be limited to while executing this recovery behavior.
~/limited_rot_speed (double, default: 0.25)

The rotational speed in radians/second the robot will be limited to while executing this recovery behavior.
~/limited_distance (double, default: 0.3)

The distance in meters the robot must move before the speed restrictions are lifted.
~/planner_namespace (string, default: "DWAPlannerROS")

The name of the planner to reconfigure parameters on. Specifically the max_trans_vel and max_rot_vel parameters will be reconfigured within this namespace.

**Comment by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) on 2021-09-14**:
These are parameters which can be adjusted, I know. But how can one enable this recovery behaviour? Moreover, it is not mentioned here: http://wiki.ros.org/nav_core#RecoveryBehavior

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-09-14**:
Agree, the documentation is lacking this info. Thank you for clarifying. I see you find the answer already, where did you find it?

**Comment by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) on 2021-09-14**:
I asked some of the folks I know. Thanks for helping :)

**Comment by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) on 2021-09-14**:
I have edited the wiki page to help others: http://wiki.ros.org/move_slow_and_clear#Implementation

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-09-14**:
Great contribution! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To use move_slow_and_clear or any custom recovery behavior, one needs to either append the following lines in move base params yaml file, or create a new yaml file and add it in the navigation launch file:

```
recovery_behaviors:
  - name: 'move_slow_and_clear'
    type: 'move_slow_and_clear/MoveSlowAndClear'
```

---

Originally posted by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) with karma: 463 on 2021-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2